# DateOnly C# doesn't bind in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dateonly

I'm using DateOnly property.
When I bind it in input it doesn't bind in default date time picker while I'm in my update view.
Though When I inspect it the "input" element has value but it doesn't bind in my calender.
Is this due to new DateOnly Property.??
As when I was using DateTimeOffset it was perfectly working

Comment: Not that hard to implement. Start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider returning a binder based on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/DateTimeModelBinder.cs swapping `DateTime` with `DateOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

`DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` hasn't support full Model Binding freature in .Net 6(refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34591)), I have tested that It has been provided in .Net 7.

If you want to use `DateOnly`, you can try to use `JsonConverter`, Refer to [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5325820/DateOnly-in-NET-6-and-ASP-NET-Core-6).